# Google Places API - Approach for Web App

Tags: android, google-places-api

Can we use Google Places API to create a review system ? Like using their API to retrieve information about that place, then storing the Key and Review in a database. Will that be possible, because Google terms and conditions are not straight forward.

If not Google, what is the best approach to develop this. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Places API does not currently return the reviews associated with requested places. There is however a Feature Request for this [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2477), if you believe that returning reviews in a request response would be a useful feature please star the issue to increase its priority and to be notified of future changes.

As per the [Google Maps Terms of Service Section 10.1.3](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3) (b)

> You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content

The only exception to this is storage of content identifier or reference key for the purpose of improving application performance.

Comment: ..Thanks for reply. I wanted to create my own review site, since there many api's for places...is it possible to use them create the site or should I be creating my own database of places (which will be a pain)?